# Run onMount of page after completion of onMount of __layout.svelte

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

Is there a way in svelte kit to execute the `onMount` function of a page, after the completion of the `onMount` function of `__layout.svelte`? In the `onMount` of `__layout.svelte` I am initializing firebase and in the `onMount` of the page, I am using firebase auth. So I can't run it without the completion of `__layput.svelte`'s `onMount`.

Also the firebase functions don't work in the `load` function as they need access to the `window` object.

Is there any better way to use firebase other than this?

__layout.svelte -

```
onMount(() => {
        let fApp: FirebaseApp;
        if (getApps().length === 0) {
            fApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        } else {
            fApp = getApp();
        }
        const fAuth = getAuth(fApp);
        $app = fApp;
        $auth = fAuth;
        onAuthStateChanged(fAuth, (user) => {
            if (user) {
                $signedIn = true;
            } else {
                $signedIn = false;
            } //app, auth and signedIn are stores
        });
    });
```

In another file I want to use firebase auth but `getAuth` returns an error that no firebase app initialized when the page is navigated to directly. The app is initializing in the layout file's `onMount` but the `onMount` of the page is called before it completes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way, but I would not recommend it *at all* because you effectively remove any server side rendering possibilities.

Simply wrap the `slot` from your layout in an if block checking an `hasMounted` flag

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  let hasMounted = false;

  onMount(() => {
    console.log("layout has mounted");
    hasMounted = true;
  });
</script>

{#if hasMounted}
  <slot />
{/if}
```

But because this flag is only set to *true* in an `onMount` it means it will never ever be *true* server side, so no more server side rendering if you go this way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So is there no way this can be achieved by server-side rendering?

Comment: none that I am aware off, but you seem to need to be client side anyway to have firebase working